# Meaning of 'born into this skin'

Tags: meaning

Recently I found this sentence:
'I was born into the position and skin to do so.'
The writer is talking about how he was fortunate to have been given the opportunity to receive higher education.

I look up 'skin' in a couple of online dictionaries, and so far the closest I have hit is from Merriam Webster, which gave me:

> 3: the life or physical well-being of a person
> saved his own skin

So in this writer's sentence, does he mean it like it was destiny for him, or saying that he was fortunate to be born into a life where he was given the opportunity?  Is it possible to substitute 'skin' with 'life'?

Comment: I would take this to mean that he felt he was fortunate to be born white, vs some other race.

Comment: "Saved his own skin", on the other hand, usually means he saved himself from some dangerous situation.

Comment: That explains!  For some reason I assumed the writer was black, and he was talking about how he just happened to be fortunate enough to be born into an environment where he was given the opportunities...
That just gave a complete context to the writer's whole post, and it makes a lot of sense now.  Watching things happening and trying to catch up from somewhere here in Asia...thank you for explaining!

Answer (score 1):

In context, he presumably means that his skin *color* helped give him the opportunities he received.